# Wordpress echo the_title in loop issue

Tags: wordpress, echo

Unable to work out a solution to this. I have set up a custom template for my wordpress theme and am trying to change the bit where there is currently an echo of the category link and title to an echo of the title of the post.

Currently the echo is:

```
echo '<h2><a href="'.$catLink.'" title="'.$category->name.'">'.$category->name.'</a></h2>';
```

Can anyone help please?

Full page code is:

```
<div id="older-posts">
<?php
// Get the current category
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) 
{ 
    $current_cat_id = $category->cat_ID; 
    break;
}

// Set the category to only the category selected
$args = array(
    'category__in' => array($current_cat_id),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$posts = new WP_Query();
$posts->query($args);

if ($posts->have_posts())
{
    while ($posts->have_posts())
    {
        echo '<div class="result">';
        echo '<h2><a href="'.$catLink.'" title="'.$category->name.'">'.$category->name.'</a></h2>';
        $posts->the_post();
        ?> 
        <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php //get thumnbnail (custom field) ?>
                    <?php $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                </a>
        </div>  </div>
        <?php 

    }   
}

// Reset global query
wp_reset_query();
?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your point. But try this:

```
//just after while() start
$posts->the_post();
?> 
<div class="result">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php //get thumnbnail (custom field) ?>
            <?php $image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail', true); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. As you suggested moving the post title and link after the $posts->the_post(); did the trick. Thanks so much!